# How to play a selected song from ListView in UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp

I am new to UWP development and trying to play a song that is displayed in my `ListView`.  The app I am writing is for a Windows IoT Core running on a raspberry pi3.

So basically what happens now is that when I select the song from my `ListView` and hit the play button nothing happens? I think I need to let the `MediaPlayer` know what song has been selected and to play that song?

This is my code I am using:

XAML:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaPlaylist" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Margin="389,-10,10,10">
        <MediaElement.TransportControls>
            <MediaTransportControls IsZoomEnabled="False" IsZoomButtonVisible='False' IsSeekBarVisible="True" IsSeekEnabled="True" IsFullWindowButtonVisible="False" IsStopButtonVisible="True"/>
        </MediaElement.TransportControls>
</MediaElement>

<ListView
         x:Name="SelectSong" 
        Margin="389,28,10,113"
        FontStyle="Oblique"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Background="DarkGreen"
        ItemClick="SongClicked"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
         />
```

C#:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _ = InitFolderAsync();

    }

private async Task InitFolderAsync()
    {
        var files = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (StorageFile item in files)
        {
            SelectSong.Items.Add(item.Name.ToString());
        }
    }

private async void SongClicked(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = e.ClickedItem as StorageFile;
        if (file != null)
        {
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            mediaPlaylist.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
            mediaPlaylist.Play();
        }
    }
```

I would like to have so that one can select a song and play it or to loop through all the songs.

Thanks

Comment: Why didn’t implement a model and viewmodel for your listview? It would be much easier to handle items and events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to play a selected song from ListView in UWP App

Please check this line `SelectSong.Items.Add(item.Name.ToString());` you just add the file's name to listview items, but not the file, so you can't get  the file with `var file = e.ClickedItem as StorageFile`.

We need to edit the `SongClicked` and get music file with cliched item like the following.

```
private async void SongClicked(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var file = await  KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(e.ClickedItem.ToString());

    if (file != null)
    {
        var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
        mediaPlaylist.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
        mediaPlaylist.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense what you said! Thanks it's working great now!  I will now look to get it to play the next song automatically.  Thanks again!